# append text with html formatting to textarea with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How could i append some text to html textarea with help of jQuery library, so, that html tag's are not as text, but as formatted html tag's (see result of div tagging, not text ). now i have such js:

```
...

var currentVal = $('#article_comment_text').val();
$('#article_comment_text').val(currentVal + '<div class="quote-heading">' + comment_author + "  " + comment_date + '</div>' + '<div class="comment-quoted">' + comment_text + '</div>');


...
```

is it real? and how could i do, that text, which append to textarea is styled, not just views as text  etc?

Comment: Textareas don't render their value/content as HTML. Maybe you are looking for a contenteditable div, or you simply render the content in a div as preview.

Comment: @FelixKling i need it for commenting.... how can i do than? maybe just to hide <div> in textarea and change for example to some <quote> but just for userview

Comment: As I said, you cannot render HTML inside a textarea. I'm not sure what you mean by "I need it for commenting". If you want to show to the user how their comment would look like, show it in a separate div (just like Stack Overflow does it for questions and answers).

Comment: You need to use contenteditable div as Felix Kling suggestion. Check my answer.

Comment: @FelixKling ok i will take a look, i want to do something like SMF forum do, hm ) i understand that i couldn't explain what i want normal))) you say a good try, just that with such edition - user didn't must see this html code in textarea, but it must be send via post request as textarea value

Comment: @ValdisAzamaris: Oh I see. I wouldn't store HTML in a database (I assume that's what you are trying to do). I'd rather store the raw data and build the HTML when the comment is rendered. But if you want to store the HTML, you could either generate it on the server prior to saving, or create a hidden input element that holds the HTML string.

Comment: @FelixKling  I'd rather store the raw data and build     - please advice - how to store it, how could i then rebuild and render it, how can i understand that this is comment from such person etc

Comment: Well, you store `comment_author`, `comment_date` and the comment text in the DB and then you generate the HTML from that like you generate your other HTML. I cannot give you a tutorial in databases and whatever server side language you are using here. Find one on the web.

Comment: @FelixKling thank's a lot, just then will be trouble if i wanna to quote quoted many times comment

Answer (score 1):

Edit:

You cannot render HTML inside textarea, you need to use contenteditable div:

```
<div class="textarea" contenteditable="true">This is a test</div>
```

Then you can do something like:

```
$('.textarea').html(function() {
    return '<strong>' + $(this).html() + '</strong>';
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EcDKt/1/)**

Comment: how would you pass this to php through $_post?

Answer (score 0):

If i get your question right ? 
So,
There is noway to insert HTML inside `<textarea></textarea>` so it isn't formated !
You have to make a clone of `textarea`,with a property of `contenteditable`;

Comment: To correct way to get the value of a textarea is `.val`, not `.text`.

Comment: Both are same its up to you,, but its my suggestion that if want to add custom style inside text area then you have to use `contenteditable` property on a cloned HTML element.